# Games laggy in Chrome

Tags: browser, chrome-for-android, lineageos, webview, lagging

I have the following system: Galaxy SIII i9300 with LineageOS 14.1 (latest Nightly), rooted. I would like to play a particular game (I usually do not play browser games) against some one to show him that my S3 is still able to handle it. It is not a Flash game, but pure JavaScript.

I've tried to play the game in Chrome. It is pretty fast but very - I do not know how to describe it in English - jumpily or shakily which does not do good for the eyes after some time. Jelly, in turn, which is based on Android WebView is able to render the game smoothly without jumps but is a bit slower than on Chrome.

I am certain that you can tweak Chrome somehow to render the games better on older phones. I played with some flags (GPU flags and so on) but could not achieve any improvement. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The really first thing you should do is delete the entire history in Chrome. Sometimes this leads to strange behaviors.

The second address would be:

```
    chrome://flags
```

1. Override software rendering list
2. GPU rasterization
3. Number of raster threads
4. V8 caching mode.

If you are already using Developer Options - Force GPU rendering, it might help to use an older Chrome version (I was forced to do this because the latest version always crashes).If all this does not bring anything, I recommend you to switch to another browser like (Puffin etc.), which offload certain things, but i think you know this already.